# How create debug keystore for a "Google Play App Signing" project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-games, android-keystore, android-app-signing

for a debug keystore (when run a application directly out of android studio which is working with google play services - doing a sign in and so on) you have to make a debug keystore.      But with the new feature "Google Play App Signing" the generated keystore is a "Upload Key (google invented it)" with a special Upload Signature.  The problem is (i guess) that i need a debug keystore with an App Signature (i guess).  So the question is: How can i create a debug keystore with the "App signature" (the MD5 and SHA-1 i know for this), to make it possible to run signed apps out of the IDE that can sign into google play services?

Answer (score 2):

[Debug keystores](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#debug-mode) are automatically created for you by Android Studio the first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key passwords.

However, if you're looking to sign your app, you can execute this [command in the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually):

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks
-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the `debug.keystore` command, then you can go to google cloud platform, then credentials from left menu.

After that, find your application, check the package name and click on it.

In new window, you should find a command to regenerate your `debug.keystore`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new one(debug or release or profile) from android studio:

1. go to build generate signed Bundle/Apk
   [image]
2. then click next then create new
   [image]
3. then enter the red info & click next
   [image]
4. choose keystore type