# I have a flutter app that has ci cd(code magic) & Google signin which fails because of SHA1 change?

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

> gives: PlatformException(sign_in_failed,com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

I have a flutter app that has ci/cd & Google sign in which fails because of `SHA1` change Because of the change of the machine that builds the apk in debug mode so how to make the google sign in work on the ci/cd apk or How to add the ci/cd machine `SHA1` to firebase to. make the google sign in work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. generate keystore like this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75350479/8316183)
2. open the keystore with keystore explorer [here](https://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html)
3. copy SHA1 & add it to firebase android app
   [image]
4. add the keystore to code magic
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate signing key for the debug build type or copy the existing one which was created by your development machine.

Copy the debug signing key into your project folder and configure it in gradle.

Example: Create a signing key namend `debug.keystore` with the alias `androiddebugkey` and password `android`. Then create a folder named `keystore` in your android project directory and copy the keystore into it. You can assign a debug signing key in the app module's `build.gradle` file like this:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('.././keystore/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
```

This way all developers and the CI/CD systems use the same debug signign key.

Comment: It needs some more steps to work I'll put it in an answer